# Operand stack underrun

Tags: java, bytecode

I have this program to generate bytecode from a java file.
And for this simple test() method

```
public void test()
{
    boolean a = false;
    if (a || true)
    {
         boolean b = false;
    }
}
```

, it would generate the follow piece of bytecode

```
public void test()
  Code:
   7:   iconst_0
   8:   istore_1
   9:   iload_1
   10:  ifne    13
   13:  iconst_0
   14:  istore_2
   15:  return
```

When I execute the class, I keep getting `Operand stack underrun in test()`, which I couldn't figure out why because the generated bytecode looks good (to me)

Could anyone help me debug this?

(Here's what I did to trace the stack

```
public void test()
  Code:
   7:   iconst_0
 (1 on the stack)
   8:   istore_1
 (0 on the stack)
   9:   iload_1
 (1 on the stack)
   10:  ifne    13
 (0 on the stack)
   13:  iconst_0
 (1 on the stack)
   14:  istore_2
 (0 on the stack)
   15:  return
```

So yeah, the stack looks fine to me!)

EDIT: Here's the generated bytecode by `javac`

```
public void test();
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0
   1:   istore_1
   2:   iload_1
   3:   ifne    6
   6:   iconst_0
   7:   istore_2
   8:   return
```

Comment: What does `javac` generate for the same code?

Comment: You appear to have optimised `|| true` away in correctly.  You have treated it as `&& true`

Comment: No, that's not true. But even if it were, it still wouldn't explain why I'm getting the stack-underrun error. (Just updated the question with `javac-`generated bytecode. ANd it's pretty much the same)

Comment: `a || true` => `true` so you wouldn't load `a` or have a conditional branch.  The problem is in the fact that its "pretty much the same" but not the same. ;)

Comment: But the `javac` also generates *the same code* (by "pretty much", I just meant the line numbering was different). But could you see any line that'd cause stack-underrun?

Comment: at which offset does it discover "Operand stack underrun"?

Comment: The exception says `11`, which is particularly confusing as I don't even have offset 11 in the method

Comment: This is indeed confusing. Even if you have somewhere "goto 11" the code should be rejected early by bytecode verifier. Which JVM do you use? Make a separate executable classfile (with main()) and publish somewhere so that we could explore it.

Comment: You're not generating the (royal PITA) stack depth table that was introduced around V 1.5.

Comment: If you're not using invokedynamic, it's a lot easier to set the version back to 49.0 and not worry about stack map tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try this

```
public class MainDump implements Opcodes {

    public static byte[] dump() throws Exception {

        ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(0);
        FieldVisitor fv;
        MethodVisitor mv;
        AnnotationVisitor av0;

        cw.visit(V1_7, ACC_PUBLIC + ACC_SUPER, "Main", null, "java/lang/Object", null);

        cw.visitSource("Main.java", null);

        {
            mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "<init>", "()V", null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            Label l0 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l0);
            mv.visitLineNumber(1, l0);
            mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
            mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/Object", "<init>", "()V");
            mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
            Label l1 = new Label();
            mv.visitLabel(l1);
            mv.visitLocalVariable("this", "LMain;", null, l0, l1, 0);
            mv.visitMaxs(1, 1);
            mv.visitEnd();
        }
        {
            mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "test", "()V", null, null);
            mv.visitCode();
            mv.visitInsn(ICONST_0);
            mv.visitVarInsn(ISTORE, 1);
            mv.visitVarInsn(ILOAD, 1);
            Label l2 = new Label();
            mv.visitJumpInsn(IFEQ, l2);
            mv.visitInsn(ICONST_0);
            mv.visitVarInsn(ISTORE, 2);
            mv.visitLabel(l2);
            mv.visitFrame(Opcodes.F_APPEND, 1, new Object[]{Opcodes.INTEGER}, 0, null);
            mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
            mv.visitMaxs(1, 3);
            mv.visitEnd();
        }
        cw.visitEnd();

        return cw.toByteArray();
    }

    public static void main(String... ignored) throws Exception {
        Method defineClass = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("defineClass", byte[].class, int.class, int.class);
        defineClass.setAccessible(true);

        byte[] dump = dump();
        defineClass.invoke(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader(), dump, 0, dump.length);
        new Main().test();
    }
}
```

This works, however if I drop the stack frame adjustment, I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 8
Exception Details:
  Location:
    Main.test()V @3: ifeq
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 033c 1b99 0005 033d b1
```

In short, for Java 7, the stack operations are not enough to pass validity.

Comment: (I'm new to compiler stuff ( < 2 months, so please bear with me)). But what is the problem again? Could maybe put it in an easier way to understand? Are you saying switching to java-6 would solve the problem?

Comment: @OneTwoThree - About 5 years ago Sun added added a new "feature" to the bytecode format that requires you to  provide a table of stack contents for each branch target.  They apparently added this to speed up their (incredibly poor) verifier, rather than simply fix it.  But it makes generating bytecodes a PITA.

Comment: @OneTwoThree I am saying you need stack frame information. Without it the verifier gets confused.

Comment: I see. I'm gonna mark yours as the answer, (although I think I'm gonna have to re-think my problem/question. Maybe I was asking the wrong question). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your bytecode doesn't start at offset 0. I don't know what the first 6 bytes are doing, but whatever it is, it's not going to verify.

Comment: I simplified the file, because the first part is for fields declaration and whatnot.

Comment: @One well unfortunately your simplification makes it impossible to help. Please post the complete classfile.

Answer (score 0):

Every method must specify its stack frame size, `max_stack`, (two booleans/ints here) in the .class. In the  [code attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html#1546), which also contains the instructions.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean here. This is not a .class file, by the way.